# Divide data for training and test set with all subject in the training set

Tags: python-2.7, svm, cross-validation, libsvm

I am new to machine learning and I am trying to deal with SVM. I have a corpus with nearly 3000 data with around 47 subjects which i plan to do a 10 fold cross validation with. But how do i make sure that all 47 subjects are in the each of the group in the 10 groups during the cross validation?

for example, some of the topics are 'apple','blackberry', 'sony','canon','htc'. I want to make sure all the groups in cross validation contains 'apple','blackberry','sony','canon','htc', etc meaning that Group 1 - Group 10 has them.

So how do I ensure this? Should I separate the data by subjects first then only split them each into 10 groups,then only to merge all of them together?

But if so, does this means that I have manually split the 10 groups data into training and test set , for 10 times(manual cross validation) then only pass to libSVM? or I only have to prepare 10 groups with all the subjects in them then let libSVM do the automated cross validation -v 10?

And back to the main topic, how can i program in Python to split the data? My data have 2 columns(tabs) one for their subject, one for the content/text.

Answer (score 1):

***You can use sklearn Library for splitting the data***

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split    
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(df,tar,test_size=0.30)
```

The above code will split the data into training and testing in the ration 7:3 and shuffle them so that you can get all the target values for training and validation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is called **stratification**. It ensures that, when splitting the data, the percentage of samples in each of the classes is preserved.

In python this can be easily done with scikit-learn:

- For splitting the data into train/test sets you dan use [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). According to the docs, by default it splits the data in a stratified fashion. You can even modify this by passing in an argument to `stratify`.
- For generating folds for cross-validation you can use [sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html).
- If you want to use sklearn for training your models I'd suggest you use [sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html).